# Can FallbackResource support wildcards?

Tags: apache

Here is my Directory configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/sub-dir/*>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted 
    FallbackResource /sub-dir/*/index.php
</Directory>
```

However, this directive does not seem to work.

Is there a method to accomplish this? Or would it be best to Fallback to a PHP routing script?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit:

I have found the `<DirectoryMatch>` tag and have decided it is probably what I was looking for. However, the syntax evades me. Here is what I have currently:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/sub-dir/(?<chindex>[0-9])">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted 
    FallbackResource /subdir/%{env:MATCH_CHINDEX}/index.php
</DirectoryMatch>
```

My `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html`

I have two directories:

`/var/www/html/sub-dir/0/`
`/var/www/html/sub-dir/1/`

I want this rule to apply to both directories, but using the `index.php` contained within the respective directories (at `/0/index.php` and `/1/index.php`, respectively).

The server currently errs for 400 Bad Request when typing https://domain.tld/sub-dir/0/Extraneous-Text-That-Should-Trigger-FallbackResource

Which part of my syntax is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `/var/www/html` is your `DocumentRoot`, use:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/sub-dir/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted 
    FallbackResource /sub-dir/index.php
</Directory>
```

The fallback page `/sub-dir/index.php` would be used for non-existing paths below `/sub-dir/` 
like `/sub-dir/foo.php` or `/sub-dir/foo/bar.php` and you can access the original URL via the PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable.

For a different fallpage page under a sub-directory of `/var/www/html/sub-dir/` like `/var/www/html/sub-dir/sub-dir2` you would need another `FallbackResource`, e.g:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/sub-dir/sub-dir2/>
    FallbackResource /sub-dir/sub-dir2/index.php
</Directory>
```

or implement a routing/include mechanism in `/sub-dir/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the post to elaborate and hopefully clarify a few things.

Comment: Ok, I saw your edit now. I don't think this is possible with `FallbackResource`. According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) you can only use a simple URL here, nothing fancy. I would probably use a fallback like in my first example and use PHP as a controller to include content from `/sub-dir/0/index.php` or parts from a template using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine the original URL.